# Passing valueChangeListener method expression into tag file

Tags: jsf, tagfile

I have a `<h:inputText>` with an event listener like following:

```
<h:inputText valueChangeListener="#{myBean.handle}"/>
```

I would like to put it in a tag file which is to be used as follows:

```
<my:itext changeListener="#{myBean.handle}" />
```

With inside the tag file:

```
<h:inputText valueChangeListener="#{changeListener}" />
```

However it's evaluating it as a property instead of as a listener method. How can I pass the listener method into a tag file?

Comment: In other words, `<my:itext>` isn't actually a component, but a tag file?

Comment: Yes @BalusC "itext" is defined in a tagspace called "my" and I need to specify the handler outside the real component (h:inputText) but in the caller (who write my:itext ...)

Comment: Are you using JSP or Facelets? Which version?

Comment: I'm in a Seam environment and cannot use other than jstl jsf richfaces injection/outjection.

Comment: I didn't ask that. Are you using JSP or Facelets? Simpler worded, do your JSF pages have the `.jsp` or `.xhtml` extension?

Comment: Okay, you're thus using Facelets. Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by design not pass method expressions as a tag file attribute. You basically need to convert the `ValueExpression` to a `MethodExpression` inside the tag file.

For JSF 2.x Facelets, this can be solved using [OmniFaces `<o:methodParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/methodParam).

```
<o:methodParam name="changeListenerMethod" value="#{changeListener}" />
<h:inputText valueChangeListener="#{changeListenerMethod}" />
```

However, for old and deprecated Facelets 1.x or JSP 2.x there is no existing solution. The OmniFaces `<o:methodParam>` is however open source, you should be able to copy and alter it for Facelets 1.x or JSP if necessary.

Note that when you're actually already using JSF 2.x, you could also use a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) instead. This supports passing method expressions as `<cc:attribute method-signature>`. For JSF 1.x you can alternatively also create a *real* custom component, but that's a bit more work than just some XML.

Comment: mmhmm. valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeListenerMethod}" needs that bean have a method changeListenerMethod(ValueChangeEvent e) and I use it! The problem of passing the "controller" is that the ValueChangeEvent parameter of changeListenerMethod is not passed, so I cannot do some works with the valuechangeevent. Sigh!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concrete problem. I've already answered that.

Comment: Sorry @BalusC but I cannot use other libraries (even free or open). I think I'll create my big own components. I'll search for a guideliness on google.

Comment: I close the question because I see, like @BalusC told me, there is no way to do in JSF 1.2 without any addon-libraries. I'm trying doing this using a "normal" a4j:support. Hoping this way bring me to the correct way...